# Dynamically added cells disappear while exporting to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-columns, rowdatabound

I have a gridview. I have created two columns dynamically in the Row_DataBound event of the gridview.

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        cell1.Width = 100;
        e.Row.Cells.Add(cell1);

        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
        cell2.Width = 100;
        e.Row.Cells.Add(cell2);
    }
    else
    {
        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        cell1.Width = 100;
        cell1.Text = "<span style='font-weight:bold'>Total Punches";
        e.Row.Cells.Add(cell1);

        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
        cell2.Width = 110;
        cell2.Text = "<span style='font-weight:bold'>Hours Worked";
        e.Row.Cells.Add(cell2);
    }
```

I want to export the whole grid to Excel sheet. When I click the Export button, the last two columns which I created on Row_DataBound disappear in the excel sheet.

Can anyone help me solving this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are these columns visible when you post back?

Comment: No. How do I add these columns in PostBack.I do not know how to do that because I am creating these columns in RowDataBound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to move the logic to `RowCreated` event.